# redirect issue after wepay payment success in php

Tags: php, url, redirect, payment, wepay

I have a problem to redirect after wepay payment success means how can I redirect after this wepay url

```
https://stage.wepay.com/status/checkout_complete/1233455
```

and this is my code

```
try { 
    $data['checkout']= $wepay->request('/checkout/create', array(
            'account_id' => $account_id, // ID of the account that you want the money to go to
            'amount' => 1, // dollar amount you want to charge the user
             'currency' => 'USD',
            'short_description' => "this is a test payment", // a short description of what the payment is for
            'type' => "goods", // the type of the payment - choose from GOODS SERVICE DONATION or PERSONAL              
        )
    );
    // print_r($data['checkout']);
} catch (WePayException $e) { // if the API call returns an error, get the error message for display later
    $data['error'] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how to redirect a user after a checkout is complete in the documentation: https://developer.wepay.com/api/api-calls/checkout#create.

You need to use the `hosted_checkout` structure.  This only works if you are using the [WePay iFrame or Hosted page](https://developer.wepay.com/docs/process-payments/embedded-checkout) for processing payments.

```
$data['checkout']= $wepay->request('/checkout/create', array(
        'account_id' => $account_id,
        'amount' => 1,
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'short_description' => "this is a test payment",
        'type' => "goods", 
        'hosted_checkout' => array( // hosted checkout structure
           'redirect_uri' => "http://google.com" // the url for redirect
        )    
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
$data['checkout']= $wepay->request('/checkout/create', array(
        'account_id' => $account_id, // ID of the account that you want the money to go to
        'amount' => 1, // dollar amount you want to charge the user
         'currency' => 'USD',
        'short_description' => "this is a test payment", // a short description of what the payment is for
        'type' => "goods", // the type of the payment - choose from GOODS SERVICE DONATION or PERSONAL
        'redirect_uri' => "http://google.com", // the url for redirect


    )
);
```

Comment: this redirect_uri array index can not supported in create already check it

Comment: ERROR: redirect_uri parameter is unexpected

Comment: https://developer.wepay.com/docs/process-payments/embedded-checkout
They mentioned it in their step 1 explanation and explained it in step 3

Comment: can you understand ?

Comment: can any one help me i have still same issue ?